# Get text from third party application and insert into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to automatically retrieve the text of a popup box from an external application. i would need this text to be inserted into a cell in my excel. any idea how?

i am using appactivate and sendkeys to send keystrokes to this application, now i need to do the reverse, to pick up the generated text and insert into my excel.

thanks!

Comment: just an in house application. i will key in the details, and the application will generate a reference number. [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/28vqdd5.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about a message box, Ctrl + C copies to clipboard.